# Issue while running a dotnet solution using IIS Express

Tags: asp.net

I have a dotnet application. I am trying to debugging the solution and i am getting the following error message. I tried adding the dll in local GAC, tried running using x86 CPU. but still getting the issue. I am trying to debug the code on my local machine using IIS express.

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +225
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +110
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +48

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +767
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +256
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +58
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +281
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +69
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +137
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +848

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +714
```

Comment: How you try to debugging it ? its runs with out the debugger ? what is the version of sql server, what is the version of visual studio, how you try to add the dll on gac ? you need to setup them, not add them

Comment: Go into project settings - try setting the web server to run as x64 bits - if that don't work, then try again setting it as x32

Comment: @Aristos - I was debugging. I haven't tested with out debugging. we are using sql server 2016. I had copied the dll C:\windows\system32\assemblies directory on my local machine.

Comment: @krishna no, you must install them, not just copy them. Actually, you must not touch that directories... they go together with many registry entries

Comment: @krishna The debugger is not start so easy with iis - probably you run the visual studio web server not the iis

Comment: @Aristos - I tried registering using gacutil as well. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @krishna can you run it with out the debugger on a web page ?